# Saving edits - ellipse turns into rugged polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, save

I am having great problems when saving edits – whenever I create an ellipse, circle, freehand or feature with Bezier curve, it stands only until saving – then it turns into rugged polygon.
Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1., coordinate system S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North. Features in question are 10 m in width most, usually half the size.
[image: before]
[image: after]
I’ve tried Smooth in Advanced editing but it won’t save either, couldn’t find anything that would change the process either in Data Frame Properties or Editor Options.
The answer must be somewhere else, I tried to change the maximum number of polygon vertices created during vectorization (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/setting-the-maximum-number-of-vertices-created-in-vectorization.htm) but that does not seem to be related. All in all, I am pretty stuck with this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't specified what format you are saving to, but sounds like it's a format that doesn't support true curves, like a shapefile for example.

Comment: thank you for your reply - that is indeed true, I save to shapefile. So there is no way around it? at least forcing the program to create more vertices - thus making the line more curve-like? thank you again, for replying so early!

Comment: It's unclear from your question what the size of the geometries are, and how your spatial reference is defined. If you're placing ellipses around parking lots in UTM with 0.1mm precision you'll get a different geometry than placing ellipses around stumps in WGS84 degrees. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: I'm afraid this is just another reason to avoid shapefile (as if the other dozen weren't enough).

Comment: It is a limitation of shapefiles.  But I'll note I had to ban true curves from my GIS layers because they screwed up complex overlays and some software couldn't use them properly.  I don't know if GDAL even supports them yet.  radouxju's answer should get you what you want.    This might be interesting: https://community.esri.com/t5/geoprocessing-questions/true-curves-true-evil/td-p/160790

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentionned in the comment, shapefile do not use true curves. Because you work at a large scale (1:50 if I see well) your ellipse is generalized with a limited number of vertices. The clean solution is to use a feature dataset inside a geodatabase. The workaround is to densify your polygons (geoprocessing tools -> editing -> densify) BEFORE you save your edit. See my results without (left) and with (right) "densify". I've used a small distance (in my case, 1cm) so that you don't see that it is composed of straight lines, but of course this will largely increase the size of your shapefile, so to "optimize" the number of vertices, you can use a distance that is equivalent to 0.3 mm on the map at the minimum visualisation scale (most people will not see that it  is made of straigth lines with this distance).

[image]

The image below shows the vertices of the true curve (like in a geodatabase), the default shapefile generalization and the feature with densified vertices.

[image]